# a global and local map question

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap-2d, global-costmap, local-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the image below there are two blue crest. If I toggle off the global map panel then the right one disappears.  If I toggle off the local map panel then the left one disappears. My global static map in the map server is blank so the image is real-time! Why are these not aligned?

```
rosmap.yaml  for map server

image: rosmap.pgm
resolution: 0.005000
origin: [-10.000000, -10.000000, 0.000000]
negate: 0
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196


costmap_common_params.yaml for common costmap parameters

obstacle_range:         2.5
raytrace_range:         3.0
footprint:              [[0.25, 0.1], [0.25, -0.1], [-0.25,-0.1], [-0.25, 0.1]] 
max_scaling_factor:     0.02  # The scalling factor for footprint defined in local costmap
inflation_radius:       0.02 # Propagating cost values out from occupied cells that decrease with distance.
map_type:               costmap
track_unknown_space:    true
observation_sources:    laser_scan_sensor 
laser_scan_sensor:      {sensor_frame: hokuyo_frame, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
resolution:             0.005

local_costmap:
  global_frame:      /odom
  robot_base_frame:  /base_link
  update_frequency:  10.0
  publish_frequency: 10.0
  static_map:        true
  rolling_window:    false
  width:             16.0
  height:            16.0
  origin_x:          -8.0
  origin_y:          -8.0


global_costmap:
  global_frame:        /map
  robot_base_frame:    /base_link
  update_frequency:    30.0
  publish_frequency:   30.0
  static_map:          true
  width:               20.0
  height:              20.0
  origin_x:            -10.0
  origin_y:            -10.0
```

Static map:

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94021/a-global-and-local-map-question/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-10-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-10-25**:
You should add how you configured your costmaps, especially their origins and staticness.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-10-25**:
I updated question with this information,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The local map should not be configured to use the static map.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-10-25**:
please see http://answers.ros.org/question/93686/preplexing-local-cost-map-problem/
i will close this but it right now it is the only way I have of running. OK.just tested if I just keep DWA off the static map can be off also and it will move forward.